# SilverStripe 3 custom routing Wildcard

Tags: routes, wildcard, silverstripe

I'd like to create a custom routing covering anything to start with.

Is it possible to set a wildcard in routing?

For example `http://example.com/*/show/urlsegment`

I have tried many things without success.

```
Director::addRules(100, array(
    '*/show//$EventUrlSegment' => 'MyTest_Controller'
));
```

What is the right syntax to cover anything before `/show`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Silverstripe 3.* you should use the yaml file, found in the `_config` folder.
You can define your wildcard by using `$` like you did with `EventUrlSegment`

```
Director:
  rules:
    '$Action/show/$EventUrlSegment' : 'MyTest_Controller'
```

Comment: I've edited my question. Still want to know about a WILDCARD